# Best way to install MythTV?

Tags: wubi, mythbuntu, mythtv

I've got a Windows Media Center pc at the moment, but I would like to change to Ubuntu ... if I can make it work. [This related topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/95473/5786) recommends that I use MythTV, and from that I have a new question:

Given that I have a working Windows machine that I want to keep as a fall-back, would **installing Wubi with the Mythbuntu choice** be the simplest way to get a fully working Ubuntu-based media center?

Note that this computer is not just for watching DVD's -- I want to watch **live TV** and schedule recordings from live TV. I receive ~40 analog channels and 4 digital (DVB-T) channels through the same antenna cable on a single tv card. This works fine in Windows and I hope that Ubuntu / MythTV can handle that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with Wubi, or, alternatively, to resize the Windows partition, create a Linux partition in the free space and install Mythbuntu there. The latter approach is probably more future-proof in case you decide to get rid of Windows... also, you're going to need *a lot* of disk space for recordings, so a separate hard drive will be the ultimate solution.

Comment: I've got a separate 1TB drive for the media files and I expect that I can point MythTV there to pick up the recordings, movies, etc. If this Mythbuntu approach proves successful (wife acceptance factor) then I would do a clean install - but for now, Wubi is a very slick way to do a test run.